# Testing MySQL connection in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm working at learning mocha and chai.
Thought I was keeping it simple with a database connection test.

The tests seemed fine at first, but something made me look closer.
The tests were succeeding, so they should also fail under certain circumstances too right?
I wanted to see a fail so I forced a scenario

```
it('db.connection.connect should return a connection object using default config.js credentials ', function(){
    var result = "FAIL!";
    db.connection.connect(function(err, result) {
        if(err){
            console.log("SQL CONNECT ERROR: " + err);
            result=(err);
        } else {
            //console.log("SQL CONNECT SUCCESSFUL.");
            //result = "SQL CONNECT SUCCESSFUL.";
            console.log("Test succeeded but result should show fail");
        }
        expect(result).to.equal("SQL CONNECT SUCCESSFUL.");
    });
});
```

However, now the test won't succeed. The "result" variable is never altered as expected.

```
it('db.connection.connect should return a connection object using default config.js credentials ', function(){
    var result = "FAIL!";
    db.connection.connect(function(err, result) {
        if(err){
            console.log("SQL CONNECT ERROR: " + err);
            result=(err);
        } else {
            console.log("SQL CONNECT SUCCESSFUL.");
            result = "SQL CONNECT SUCCESSFUL.";
            //console.log("Test succeeded but result should show fail");
        }
    });
    expect(result).to.equal("SQL CONNECT SUCCESSFUL.");
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the test is asynchronous and the function you are passing to Mocha does not include a callback.

If you pass a function that accepts a callback function, Mocha will pass a callback that you can invoke to inform Mocha that the test is complete:

```
it('db.connection.connect should ...', function(done) {
    db.connection.connect(function(err, result) {
        if(err){
            done(err);
            return;
        }
        expect(result).to.equal("SQL CONNECT SUCCESSFUL.");
        done();
    });
});
```

Call `done` with no arguments to inform Mocha that the test is complete.

Note that `done` can be passed an error, in which case Mocha will fail the test.

Comment: Cool. The done callback let's Mocha know the test is done.
As it turns out, this particular test is returning the object OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 0,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }

So I think I did the test wrong on yet another level.

Comment: You'll need to adjust the expectation in the answer to suit what's actually received. There was a variable named `result` in your code as well as a parameter named `result`, so it was unclear what was what. But your core problem was the lack of a callback. If you comment out the expectation - or replace it with something that better reflects what's received - you should have a passing test.

Comment: @cartant is it important to test database connection in test cases?

Comment: @Prashant Whether or not I'd test it would depend upon whether or not the connector was something I'd written, or whether or not the test was part of some integration test, etc. There's not enough context in the question to say much else. Anyway, I wasn't looking at the context; only the missing callback.

Comment: As I pointed out in my question, testing the database connection seemed like a simple example for learning testing methodology. I figured since I have a working connection, it would be an easy test case for success or failures. Clearly I was wrong.

Comment: I want to point out that testing the DB connection was actually usedul until I completed things by trying to make getter setter methods, do module exports and the like. These changes made the testing more complex.
When I tested the basic mysql.createConnection functionality, I found some hidden gotchas about how my database was configured that would have given me a much bigger headache without testing.
I tested the simplest database access script functionality. Worth my time.